# margin auto, float and parent height

Tags: html, css, height, margin

after several research and test, i still don't understand how to fixe properly the margin-auto & float:left problem.

You can find my code here :
http://jsfiddle.net/pierrearfarf/6VfMh/

With this solution, the div #projets have no height, and I have no idea how to fix this.
visualy my solution works but seems to be weird. Could someone tell me if there is a better solution ?

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content_wrapper">
        <div id="projets">
            <ul id="projets_content">
                <li class="projet">test 1</li>
                <li class="projet">test 2</li>
                <li class="projet">test 2</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main{
float:left;
width:100%;
margin:0px;
padding:0px;    
}
#content_wrapper{
float:left;
    width:100%;
border:1px solid cyan;
margin-top:15px;
}

#projets{
width:160px;
border:1px solid black;
margin:10px auto;
}   

ul#projets_content{
float:left;
width:100%;
padding:0px;
border:1px solid blue;
list-style:none;
text-align:left;
}

ul#projets_content li {
width:35px;
margin:0px;
border:1px solid red;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: you do not need those many float and width:100%, you may use display http://jsfiddle.net/6VfMh/2/

Comment: thanks for your answer @GCyrillus I did not know display as table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6VfMh/1/

I added the following

```
#projets {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and

```
#content_wrapper {
   text-align: center;
}
```